# ERROR TypeError: this.dataService.getMovie is not a function

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use a service to get JSON object but when trying to use the service method I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.dataService.getMovie is not a function

My code:

**DataService:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  getMovieURL = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=27f198d0&t=';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getMovie(title: string): Observable<Movie> {
    return this.http.get<Movie>(this.getMovieURL + title);
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  moviesToLoad = ["The Predator","Skyscraper","Avengers: Infinity War","Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom","Black Panther"];
  moviesArray:Array<Movie>=[];

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) {
    
    for(let i =0; i<this.moviesToLoad.length; i++){
      this.dataService.getMovie(this.moviesToLoad[i]).subscribe(res=> {
        this.moviesArray.push(res);
      })
    }
    
   }
```

**html:**

```
<div *ngFor='let c of moviesArray'>
  
    {{moviesArray.Title}}
  
  </div>
```

what could cause that?

Comment: Looks fine by me, could you reproduce your issue on https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: mm how could I generate new service over there?

Comment: what do  `console.log(dataService)` and `console.log(this.dataService)` show in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

forgot to add the service to the app.modules. problem solved thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

in app.module:

```
 providers: [
    {
      provide: ABDataService,
      useClass: DataService,
    },
  ],
```